# typeset -U PATH not working in macos terminal zsh

Tags: macos, zsh

typeset -U PATH not working in macos terminal zsh:

```
typeset -U PATH
```

Error:

```
typeset: -U: invalid option
typeset: usage: typeset [-afFirtx] [-p] name[=value] ...
```

Do you know why?

Comment: You aren't using `zsh`. That's the error message raised by `bash` 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Like @chepner said, you are probably not on `zsh` because I tried it like you on Macosx with zshell 5.3 and it works.

For reference, here is the `zsh` [man page for all the builtins](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins).